# Grants accessible to Italian mathematicians?

Tags: mathematics, funding, career-path, italy

**What kind of grants can mathematicians working in Italy apply to?**

In addition to the various [ERC grants](https://erc.europa.eu/homepage) are there any other specific funding programmes that mathematicians working in Italy may apply to (at local, national or international level)?

Comment: This seems to be a pretty clear example of a [shopping question](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3657/why-was-my-question-put-on-hold-for-shopping) to me, but it has attracted positive votes and no close votes, which surprises me a bit but also makes me hesitant to close with a mod vote.

Comment: @BryanKrause Not really a "shopping question" -- more like an "existence question"; and, it seems, not a trivial one since after two days there are still no answers from the considerable number of Italian mathematicians that are active on Academia SE

Comment: @BryanKrause Italy might be a bit different with respect to other countries because funding at the national level comes mostly from the ministry. Kei, there aren't probably many Italian mathematicians on this site (one, afaik). I'm Italian, but not a mathematician, and that's why I'm hesitant answering this question because I don't know if the sources I use are also used by mathematicians (e.g. have you considered the PRIN?). Moreover I mostly use European funds.

Comment: I would really appreciate it if this question could stay open. In addition to OP's (quite reasonable, imho) argument that this is about existence rather than about shopping, I find it really refreshing to have a country specific question now and then in which the country is not the United States. ;-)

Comment: (Needless to add, no offence intended towards the colleagues from the US.)

Answer (score 3):

The first that come to my mind are:

- The [ERC grants](https://erc.europa.eu/homepage) that you already mentioned, in particular the starting/consolidator/advanced grants, which are not tied to industry applications.
- [PRIN](https://prin.mur.gov.it/) for collaborations that involve people that more than one university.
- smaller grants given yearly by the [INDAM research groups](https://www.altamatematica.it/en/gruppi-di-ricerca/gruppi-nazionali/).
- various local grants by universities or regions, often topic-specific. For instance my university offers [these](https://www.unipi.it/index.php/finanziamenti-di-ateneo/itemlist/category/679-pra-progetti-di-ricerca-di-ateneo) to us.
- Various past calls have been short-lived, for instance the [FIRB](https://futuroinricerca.miur.it/) or [SIR](https://sir.miur.it/) calls, or more recently the PNRR and PON calls (these are not grants technically but they give you the opportunity to hire a PhD). Probably similar ones will appear in the future, but it is impossible to predict their acronyms and timelines. :)

More generally, though, you should ask this question to your university's research support office: it is their job to have a clear picture of what calls are available and advertise them to you.